# How to bind values of enum to the ng-select tag?

Tags: angular, angular5

**I have created one enum and I want to use it in ng-select but without loop**

```
export enum JobStatusEnum {
    DEACTIVE = 0,
    NEW = 1,
    INPROGRESS = 2,
    COMPLETED = 3,
    CANCELED = 4,
    NOTASSIGNED = 5
}

<ng-select class="form-select" id="floatingSelect" aria-label="Floating label select example" [items]="JobStatusEnum" bindValue="value" bindLabel="key"></ng-select>
```

Answer (score 1):

Loop is done inside <ng-select...> component, and according to [documentation](https://github.com/ng-select/ng-select#usage)  `[items]` should receive data in this format:

```
const items = [
    { id: 0, name: 'DEACTIVE' },
    { id: 1, name: 'NEW' },
    //...
];
```

You can easily create the array using for example map function:

```
const items = Object.keys(JobStatusEnum).map(key => ({key, name: JobStatusEnum[key]}));
```

Comment: Is there any other way? like without creating const.

Comment: You could use an angular pipe to make it more generic, but still, inside the pipe, you have to manipulate the data. Why you want to avoid that?